# Adding addmob adds to main.xml crashes my app

Tags: android, admob, android-xml

Let me start by saying that this app was working fine the day before. I have restarted the pc, removed the project and added a previous version of the project and it keeps crashing. If i remove this from main.xml which gets loaded from the mainactivity the app does not crash. If i have this in the main.xml :

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="a14ee1ad68dcbdb"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

the app crashes. If i run the app and this code is  not in the main.xml file but in other xml files the app works fine and it will show adds from other activities.

I tried removing all the code in the xml file and just have the above admob adds in there and it still crashed. I was thinking about uninstalling eclipse and installing it again??? 
Any ideas????

Here is a Everything from start to finish in logcat:

```
 03-30 11:39:17.215: D/AndroidRuntime(338): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
03-30 11:39:17.215: D/AndroidRuntime(338): CheckJNI is ON
03-30 11:39:17.335: D/AndroidRuntime(338): --- registering native functions ---
03-30 11:39:17.825: D/AndroidRuntime(338): Shutting down VM
03-30 11:39:17.825: D/dalvikvm(338): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-30 11:39:17.845: I/AndroidRuntime(338): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
03-30 11:39:18.215: D/AndroidRuntime(346): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
03-30 11:39:18.215: D/AndroidRuntime(346): CheckJNI is ON
03-30 11:39:18.345: D/AndroidRuntime(346): --- registering native functions ---
03-30 11:39:18.835: I/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter uid=10040
03-30 11:39:18.835: I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 331 SIG: 9
03-30 11:39:18.896: I/UsageStats(59): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter
03-30 11:39:18.905: W/InputManagerService(59): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@45094eb8
03-30 11:39:18.945: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter/.MainActivity }
03-30 11:39:18.945: D/AndroidRuntime(346): Shutting down VM
03-30 11:39:18.955: D/jdwp(346): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
03-30 11:39:18.955: D/dalvikvm(346): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-30 11:39:19.039: I/AndroidRuntime(346): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
03-30 11:39:19.155: I/ActivityManager(59): Start proc com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter for activity com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter/.MainActivity: pid=353 uid=10040 gids={3003}
03-30 11:39:19.345: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 285 objects / 10864 bytes in 186ms
03-30 11:39:19.475: W/ActivityThread(353): Application com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
03-30 11:39:19.525: I/System.out(353): Sending WAIT chunk
03-30 11:39:19.565: I/dalvikvm(353): Debugger is active
03-30 11:39:19.595: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 47 objects / 2056 bytes in 249ms
03-30 11:39:19.745: I/System.out(353): Debugger has connected
03-30 11:39:19.745: I/System.out(353): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-30 11:39:19.945: I/System.out(353): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-30 11:39:20.075: D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2 objects / 64 bytes in 422ms
03-30 11:39:20.207: I/System.out(353): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-30 11:39:20.405: I/System.out(353): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-30 11:39:20.605: I/System.out(353): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-30 11:39:20.823: I/System.out(353): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-30 11:39:21.025: I/System.out(353): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-30 11:39:21.225: I/System.out(353): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-30 11:39:21.468: I/System.out(353): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-30 11:39:21.677: I/System.out(353): debugger has settled (1469)
03-30 11:39:29.005: W/ActivityManager(59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
03-30 11:39:29.421: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{450bae78 com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter/.MainActivity}
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to debug the app, and it's hanging on debug.  Do you get any more relevant logs if you try to just run it?  Also, have you updated to r17 of the Android Tools by any chance?  r17 of the tools force you to place the SDK in the libs/ folder of your project.

Comment: This resolved the issue. You are great I created a libs folder and I had to put the googleadmob jar in that folder. Everything is back to normal. THANK YOU... btw create a post w/ that solution so I could make it an answer!!!

Comment: Done.  Glad that worked for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to debug the app, and it's hanging on debug. Do you get any more relevant logs if you try to just run it?

Also, have you **updated to r17 of the Android Tools** by any chance? r17 of the tools force you to place the SDK in the libs/ folder of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have stepped through a tutorial properly and added the permissions and imported the SDK?

Try stepping through this guide from the beginning:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals

Cleaning the project in Eclipse sometimes solves some problems.

Comment: I have cleaned the project a few times and that has not helped. Also this app has been on the market and its currently running adds I had this running fine and all of a sudden it failed just on the first activity that gets loaded its the problem. I am getting adds on other activities running the same code....

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar bizarre issue with Admob recently after a fresh install of Eclipse. After hours of looking into why, it ended up being my build order in the project preferences. I set the Google AdMob jar to the top, cleaned the project and all my issues were resolved.

The logcat text you have pasted does not give any error information. Can you paste the logcat text from the point of failure, generally you can see the communications with AdMob in here.

May help, just a thought.

[New version of Android LED Clock just uploaded to the market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andronicus.ledclock)

Jason

Comment: Just updated the post w/ everything that logcat is showing me when I run the app in the emulator... I really do not see anything that says admob on here, but as soon as I remove that ads from the xml in the main activity everything works fine... also the admob jar file is on top. I also removed it add it again and that did not help